# Display images from an array

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to display six images from a javascript array. Running the code below I get no results it simply seems to be not working. I have no idea where my fault is.

**Here is the javascript code:**

```
var backgroundImage = new Array(); 
backgroundImage[0] = "images/colors-wallpaper.jpg";
backgroundImage[1] = "images/florida-birds.jpg";
backgroundImage[2] = "images/focus-on-life.jpg";
backgroundImage[3] = "images/set-into-life.jpg";
backgroundImage[4] = "images/dandelion.jpg";
backgroundImage[5] = "images/flowers.jpg";
backgroundImage[5] = "images/flowers.jpg";

function displayAllImages() {
// Here has to be some error!!! //
 for (i=0;i<backgroundImage.length;i++) {
    document.write("<li><img src='" + backgroundImage[i] + "' width="160" height="120"/><span>" + backgroundImage[i] + "</span></li>");
}
}
```

**And that's my html code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javaScript" src="changebackground.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <div class="backgoundImage">
    <ul>
        <script>displayAllImages();</script>
    </ul>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: inspect with firebug or similar

Comment: I get the error Uncaught ReferenceError: displayAllImages is not defined (anonymous function)! What's the reason??

Comment: @Philipp Braun: Cause you have syntax error in this function (see my answer, you should change the quotes and this should help you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
width="160" height="120"
```

to

```
width='160' height='120'
```

In

```
document.write("<li><img src='" + backgroundImage[i] + "' width="160" height="120"/><span>" + backgroundImage[i] + "</span></li>");
```

You are using wrong quotation marks

Answer (score 2):

Your last array item key should be 6 (also I reckon as same value it's a copy/paste error) and I would strongly recommend against using document.write for such thing. Check link to see what I think you want to achieve but done in a slightly cleaner way (demo using jQuery just for the dom ready handling)

http://jsfiddle.net/UnFUB/

Comment: The only one sane enough to no use `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your double quotes, see below:

```
document.write("<li><img src='" + backgroundImage[i] + "' width=\"160\" height=\"120\"/><span>" + backgroundImage[i] + "</span></li>");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.write("<li><img src='" + backgroundImage[i] + "' width='160' height='120'/><span>" + backgroundImage[i] + "</span></li>");
```

You have a mistake in quotes. But better do not use document.write
The beeter way is to create an element in memory, and then put it in this block. How it looks on [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/yRbpD/)